# In Java Swing, is there any way to magnify what is behind a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

In Java Swing, is there any way to magnify what is behind a JFrame?

I am trying to make a magnifying glass consisting of a transparent JFrame. The area under the "glass" should be magnified, even if that area is in motion, e.g. if it contains a video.

I want to create a "magnifying glass". So that when I drag it over parts of the screen, the portion under the glass would be magnified. When I said animation, I meant that if there is anything moving under the magnifying glass, for example, if I magnify a YouTube video, the glass should show a magnified version of the video. My original approach was to capture a screenshot of the screen, and then simply magnify the portion under the glass, but that would not capture motion. Kind of like WindowsKey-+, except in Java

I have tried using a Robot with a transparent frame, but if there is any animation behind the frame, the frame just captures a still snapshot of the animation.

Comment: A screenshot is one image, so of course, a screenshot will not show any animation.  You have to minimize the JFrame, take your screenshot, and restore the JFrame.

Comment: Could you, please, give more details / clarity about what you want to do, and why you want to do it?

Comment: I am trying to make a magnifying glass consisting of a transparent frame. The area under the "glass" should be magnified, even if it is animating. Let me add that to the question

Comment: Still not clear (at least to me) what you want to achieve. Perhaps you can post some screen captures demonstrating what you are trying to do? Also, what "animation" are you referring to?

Comment: @Abra I want to create a "magnifying glass". So that when I drag it over parts of the screen, the portion under the glass would be magnified. When I said animation, I meant that if there is anything moving under the magnifying glass, for example if I magnify a YouTube video, the glass should show a magnified version of the video. My original approach was to capture a screenshot of the screen, and then simply magnify the portion under the glass, but that would not capture motion. Kind of like WindowsKey-+, except in Java

Comment: It sounds like your solutions would work if you just refresh them quick enough to show the animation.

Comment: @matt actually no, because the screen capture would copy the magnified image itself, not the image under it. Even if it could, it would be prohibitively time intensive to render that several times per second.

Comment: "... it would be prohibitively time intensive to render that several times per second." I don't understand what would be so time intensive. What about having the magnification screen not be directly over what you're magnifying? From the sounds of it you would need access to the windowing api which java doesn't supply.

Comment: I guess that is what I was asking :(